# Sysinternals psexec not running on the remote desktop

Tags: rdp, psexec, sysinternals

I've got two Remote Desktops hosted by a Hyper-V.

On Remote Desktop "A", I've got a .bat file, which I want to execute.

On Remote Desktop "B", I've got a cmd open with psexec cmd ready to invoke .bat file on machine "A".

```
"path-to\\psexec.exe" \\ip -u domain\username -p pswd -i cmd.exe /c "path-to\\myFile.bat %*"
```

The script contained in .bat file on machine "A" operates on the UI and thus requires a real screen to be open, so I am connected to two RDs simultaneously. However, when I call psexec command on machine "B", the cmd returns an error, but if I open RD "A" directly through the server's Hyper-V manager's interface, the psexec command works as expected.

Can someone explain please why this happens?

Comment: What error is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI of Windows runs on [session 0](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/). To run a program remotely that uses session 0, it will need to run as the System user (`-s` flag), and you can specify the session to use (`-i` flag). [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/428106) has a few related tips too.